# Random sampling to increase accuracy of pressure estimate?

Tags: statistics, simulation, interpolation, random, approximation

In our simulations, we have an underlying 2D grid over which a closed curve (red line) can move. Grid cells are coloured, based on the location of their centre, as either inside the curve (green) or outside the curve (blue) and can each have a different value for state variables such as pressure. For any given point in the domain, we can know precisely if it is inside or outside and interpolation can give the specific state of the point (i.e. this information is more specific than just using the cell-centered Cartesian grid).

[image: Cartoon of the grid]

We are trying to get a robust measure of 'peak' pressure inside the curve (where peak might be for instance the average of the top 1% of values).

Currently, we just take the maximum of the cell-centered values, but as you can see in the image, this can give us a very large variance each time the curve moves. I am trying to assess different options, but I am not sure about the validity of them, in particular if there are statistical techniques we can use.

Options we have considered:

1. take a random sample of `N*N*num_of_2D_cells` points on the entire grid
2. for each 2D cell, take a random sample of `N*N` points
3. subdivide each 2d cell into `N*N` smaller cells and calculate their cell-centered value

As `N` becomes large these methods should converge, however, our 2D grids can have in excess of 1e7 cells; so compute time puts an upper limit on how large `N` can be.

Does anyone have experience with -- or know of a set of literature that deals with -- this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement (knowing the average of the top 1% of the base population from a sample) **sounds like it relates to [prediction intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#Non-parametric_methods)**. I guess any specific questions on this would best be asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Do you know the **distribution of the pressure values**, or maybe some boundaries, e.g. in the sense that the pressure difference between points at distance `x` is always below `y`, or something like that? This could greatly simplify the sampling approach.

In terms of the options you propose, you could **adjust option #3 and use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to approximate the shape of the curve** (with 2d cells). Then, you could **sample randomly from those cells that are (approximately) within the curve with a frequency proportional to their area**. Doing so would avoid to take samples in regions that are not located within the curve (this would be wasted effort), and it would also avoid to further subdivide cells that are (almost) completely included in the curve. In the end, it should give you an unbiased random sample from (approximately) within the curve, on which you then could compute the statistics.